# Optimization for loop in a huge list of tuples

Tags: python, pandas, numpy

I have a list of tuples called permuted_trucks with size 38320568 and each tuple inside the list has 7 values and i am trying to insert into another list the sum of values of all tuples.

In the code below, cargo_list is a list that contain the name of the cargos (np array size 7) and distances_df is a (44, 7) pd dataframe

Truck list is a np array of size 49 with the same values of the tuple.. The tuple represent a combination of all 49 trucks picking 7 different products

I am running this loop:

```
for i in range(0, len(permuted_trucks)):
    total_distance = 0.0
    for j in range(0, len(cargo_list)):
        truck_index = np.where(truck_list == permuted_trucks[i][j])[0][0]
        total_distance += distances_df.iloc[truck_index][j]
    if (total_distance < 0 or total_distance < best_distance):
        best_distance = total_distance
        best_distance_index = i
    all_distances_index.append(i)
    all_distances.append(total_distance)
```

The problem is that it's totally slow.. and I am looking for a solution to optimize it.

Can someone help?

Example of the tuple:

```
[('Hartford',
  'Bey',
  'Empire',
  'James',
  'Ibrahim',
  'John',
  'Macomb'),
 ('Home',
  'Bey',
  'Empire',
  'James',
  'Ibrahim',
  'John',
  'Robert'),
 ('Horse',
  'Bey',
  'Empire',
  'James',
  'Ibrahim',
  'John',
  'Viking')]
```

This line below represent the sum of the distance contained in the dataframe distances_df

```
total_distance += distances_df.iloc[truck_index][j]
```

the output for all_distances would be an array of size 38320568 and the totaldistance as values like

```
[ 34125, 21252, 13232, 512313, ..... 31231]
```

Comment: Could you include an example of what is truck_list?  Is there a reason cargo_list is not used (i.e. you loop over it but do not use it in your inner for loop over j).

Comment: truck list is a np array of size 49 with the same values of the tuple..
The tuple represent a combination of all 49 trucks picking 7 different products

Comment: Thanks for the update.  Stackoverflow always recommends providing a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) to make it easy for potential responders to try out ideas.

Answer (score 0):

One straightaway improvement in speed can be achieved by using numpy array instead of data frame. Data frames are slow.

Edit: Added code to show the differences of different executions.

Importing required modules

```
import time as time
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
```

As we don't have complete information. This is what I am using to show the difference.

```
##All arrays
permuted_trucks   = np.random.randint(7,size=(100000,7))
cargo_list        = np.random.randint(7,size=(1,7))
truck_list        = np.random.randint(7,size=(49,1))

##converting arrays to lists to show difference between list and arrays
permuted_trucks_list = permuted_trucks.tolist()
cargo_list_list      = cargo_list.tolist()
truck_list_list      = truck_list.tolist()

##array
distances_df_array= np.random.randint(7,size=(44,7))

##dataframe
distances_df = pd.DataFrame(distances_df_array)
```

Now lets see your original execution list and dataframes.

```
#Time taken for lists and dataframe
start_time = time.time()
all_distances = []
all_distances_index = []
best_distance = 10
for i in range(0, len(permuted_trucks_list)):
    total_distance = 0.0
    for j in range(0, len(cargo_list_list)):
        truck_index = np.where(truck_list_list == permuted_trucks[i][j])[0][0]
        total_distance += distances_df.iloc[truck_index][j]   #using dataframe 
    if (total_distance < 0 or total_distance < best_distance):
        best_distance = total_distance
        best_distance_index = i
    all_distances_index.append(i)
    all_distances.append(total_distance)
end_time = time.time() 
print("time taken for list and data frame : {}".format(end_time-start_time))
```

Output:`time taken for list and data frame : 20.7517249584198`

lets see what happens when we use list and array (avoid dataframe).

```
#Time taken for lists and array
start_time = time.time()
all_distances = []
all_distances_index = []
best_distance = 10
for i in range(0, len(permuted_trucks_list)):
    total_distance = 0.0
    for j in range(0, len(cargo_list_list)):
        truck_index = np.where(truck_list_list == permuted_trucks[i][j])[0][0]
        total_distance += distances_df_array[truck_index,j]   #using array here
    if (total_distance < 0 or total_distance < best_distance):
        best_distance = total_distance
        best_distance_index = i
    all_distances_index.append(i)
    all_distances.append(total_distance)
end_time = time.time()
print("time taken for list and array : {}".format(end_time-start_time))
```

Output: `time taken for list and array : 3.075411319732666`

You can see a drastic improvement in the execution time

Finally, also check on all arrays.

```
#Time taken for numpy array without vectorization
start_time = time.time()
all_distances_array = np.zeros((100000,1))
all_distances_index_array = np.zeros((100000,1))
best_distance = 10
for i in range(0, len(permuted_trucks)):
    total_distance = 0.0
    for j in range(0, len(cargo_list)):
        truck_index = np.where(truck_list == permuted_trucks[i][j])[0][0]
        total_distance += distances_df_array[truck_index,j] #using array here
    if (total_distance < 0 or total_distance < best_distance):
        best_distance = total_distance
        best_distance_index = i
    all_distances_index_array[i]
    all_distances_array[i]
    end_time = time.time()    
print("time taken for numpy arrays : {}".format(end_time-start_time))
```

Output: `time taken for numpy arrays : 1.1893165111541748`

Now you see the difference, how slow data frames are. Numpys can be much faster than that if you can implement vectorization. But that can be checked only with the original data.

Comment: but only distances_df is a dataframe
Do you think the line total_distance += distances_df.iloc[truck_index][j] is turning the loop slow?

Comment: `iloc`is slow, try `distances_array = distances_df.values` and `total_distance += distances_array[truck_index][j]`

Comment: @gara Not just `iloc`, appending to `numpy` arrays is pretty slow too. It is advisable to create an empty (or zeroed) array with a predefined size (that is, if you know it beforehand) and assign values to indices of that array.

Comment: @amzon-ex appending to a list is low? I tried to append to a list (the case in the question) and create a numpy matrix of zero and assign to index, but both cases was completely slow

I also changed the dataframe to a numpy array

total_distance += distance_total[truck_index][j]

but it didnt help

Comment: I noticed that the main problem is this line:

truck_index = np.where(truck_list == permuted_trucks[i][j])[0][0]

maybe because np.where is slow?